# VLSM Subnetting: Smallest subnet first

Tags: networking, subnet, vlsm

I'm setting up a new network.

When I search on the internet and make use of subnet calculators. My largest range is always placed first.

Now I rather start with my firewalls, then place me server-range and so on.

Is there a reason for placing the largest subnet first?
I don't want to make any mistakes.

Fase 1:

[image]

Fase 2:

[image]

Comment: You're putting 4000 desktops on one subnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical reason to put some devices to lower ip numbers than others. The reason is purely for easier programming of auto-solving/subnetting software, eg:

You have a /23, and {10, 200, 50, 100} devices. You could start subnetting with /28 (16 IPs) for the 10 devices, and then a /24 for 200 devices, which leaves a unused gap between networks, and then a /26 (for 50 devices), which you could put in the gap, or after the /24 (but there's no more space there, so you go back to the gap, to check if space is there), and so on... which complicates programming (many if/else statements, and guessing where to put the networks).

It's often easier to just sort the requirements by size {200,100,50,10}, and fit the networks one after another (/24, /25, /26, /28), and you can immediately see if they fit in the given network space, and write out the correct network names and sizes.